# Cannot find mvn command after install Maven on CentOS

Tags: linux, maven, centos

I followed this tutorial to try install maven on my Remote Centos server

http://www.unixmen.com/install-apache-ant-maven-tomcat-centos-76-5/

I got /opt/maven when calling `echo $MAVEN_HOME`

And got

> /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/root/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.7/bin:/root/bin

When calling `echo $PATH`

But when I call `mvn -version` It says:

> -bash: mvn: command not found

Comment: Try running `export PATH=$PATH:/opt/maven`.  Then try `mvn -version`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you setup environment variables incorrectly. Try this section carefully: **Setup Maven environment variable** in [your tutorial](http://www.unixmen.com/install-apache-ant-maven-tomcat-centos-76-5/) what you have been seen.

Answer (score 5):

Most important command :

```
sudo ln -s /your_path/apache-maven-3.6.2/bin/mvn /usr/bin/mvn
```

Comment: THis is the correct answer hanks

Answer (score 1):

First download latest version from :

```
> http://maven.apache.org/
> go to download
> download apache-maven-3.5.0-src.tar.gz
```

Execute following commands :

```
> sudo tar xzf apache-maven-3.5.0-src.tar.gz -C /opt
> cd /opt
> Create symlink
    sudo ln -s apache-maven-3.5.0 maven
```

Next, set up Maven path system-wide :

```
> sudo gedit /etc/profile.d/maven.sh
> export M2_HOME=/opt/maven
> export PATH=${M2_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
```

Finally, log out and log in again to activate the above environment variables. To verify the successful installation of maven, check the version of maven::
> mvn -version

> > **Apache Maven 3.5.4** (1edded0938998edf8bf061f1ceb3cfdeccf443fe; 2018-06-18T00:03:14+05:30)
> > **Maven home**: /opt/maven
> > **Java version**: 1.8.0_45, **vendor**: Oracle Corporation,
> > **runtime**: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_45/jre
> > **Default locale**: en_US, **platform encoding**: UTF-8
> > **OS name**: "linux", **version**: "3.10.0-862.11.6.el7.x86_64", **arch**: "amd64", **family**: "unix"

Comment: Outdated answer. This doesn't work in docker containers

Answer (score -1):

Go to maven official website [link](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi)

```
 >  Download latest version apache-maven-3.6.3-src.tar.gz
 >  Extract it into a location.
 >  Open .bashrc file in home location ( if not found then , ctrl + h)
 >  Add maven path
```

#maven

export PATH="$PATH:

for example:
export PATH="$PATH:/home/nimal/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin"

check version :

mvn --version

[image]